# Accessing aws s3 using wildcards vs spark filters

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, partitioning

I have data stored in parquet files partioned by date.

When I try to access them using spark, I find that using the spark filter as in here:

```
basepath = 's3a://base/path/'
df_sp = sparkSession.read.parquet(basepath).filter((func.col('date_hour')>='2021-01-20-00')&(func.col('date_hour')<'2021-01-30-00'))
df_sp.count()
```

is about 10 times slower than using wildcard expressions in the path name:

```
basepath = 's3a://base/path/date_hour=2020-12-2*-00/'
df_sp = sparkSession.read.parquet(basepath)
df_sp.count()
```

When I look at the physical plan in spark, the filter version is using partition filters, so I would have thought it could be fast.

Why is the spark filter slower? Can I use the native spark functions to access this data as fast as with wildcards?

Comment: If I could understand how spark pushes filters to s3 that would help, so I would love a pointer to any documentation or source code showing that. Thanks.

Comment: the filter version might be doing partition filters but if you provide a partition with wild card filters it will do partition pruning means it won't look into some of the partitions that does not satisfy the partition that you have specified. So that is faster as compared to filter because filter would scan all the partitions and that is the reason it would be slow.